# Burst capture at 10 FPS with preview without lag

Tags: android, android-camera2

I need to do an application with an activity which captures images in burst mode at 10 FPS.
My problem is that I'm able to capture very fast pictures with the burst mode, but it seems that my buffer of images is full before I can have the time to treat them (I just want to put my images into an ArrayList).
So my buffer is full and my app crashes.

The size of the buffer that I've choose is 50 (I cannot take too much memory).
It seems that my burst mode can take 30 FPS, but I'm able to treat my images at 10 FPS.

So, I want to slow down my capturing, but when I do that (by waiting before repeat another capture), it slows down my preview too. So I have a lag in my preview.

I don't want to save my images, I just want to stock them in order to treat them later (in an other activity).

Do you have any idea, maybe to slow down my capturing, or maybe to speed up my treatment.

Code:
My code is based on the sample Camera2Basic.

```
private void captureStillPicture() {
    try {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_ABERRATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_ABERRATION_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, true);

        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.removeTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

blockCapture() permits to wait 100 ms between captures.

```
private void blockCapture() {
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.removeTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    while(Math.abs(timerBurst - System.currentTimeMillis()) < 1000){}
    System.out.println("ELAPSED :::::::: " + Math.abs(timerBurst - System.currentTimeMillis()));
    timerBurst = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    for(int i =0; i< NB_BURST; i++){captureList.add(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build());}

}

private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
        Log.d(TAG,"Saved: " + mFile);
        mCounterImageForSave ++;
        mCounterBurst++;
        if(mCounterImageForSave <= 1) {
            timerBurst = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if(mCounterBurst >= NB_BURST && isPlayed) {
            mCounterBurst = 0;
            try {
                blockCapture();
                mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),captureCallback,null);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (mCounterBurst >= NB_BURST || !isPlayed)
            unlockFocus();
    }
};
```

I have tried to capture YUV_420_888 images instead of JPEG, but my images were all black, and I cannot convert them.
Sorry if I'd make mistakes with my English.